# Proof of a theorem on the topic of alternating tensors

Tags: vectors, tensors

I need help to prove this theorem about alternating tensors and Kronecker Deltas

$\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{imn}$ = $\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn} - \delta_{jn}\delta_{km}$

I have no idea on how to go about this. Would appreciate the help

Comment: Search for "proof of epsilon-delta identity" and you'll get a ton of results